# Convert VARCHAR to BIGINT

Tags: mysql, sql, varchar, sqldatatypes, bigint

I'm trying to join two tables on two columns with different data types. One is varchar and one bigint. When executing the query I get an error saying 'Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

```
CASE WHEN c.vcCompanyNo NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
     THEN CAST (c.vcCompanyNo AS BIGINT)
     ELSE 0
     END
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Nzbn n ON c.vcCompanyNo=n.SourceRegisterUniqueIdentifier
WHERE c.daTerminationDate IS NULL
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks!

Comment: A SQL query starts with `SELECT`, so this is wrong from the first token.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As @GordonLinoff indicated, the statement is incomplete.  In addition, you're mixing regular expressions ( [^0-9] ) with SQL Like syntax (Percent characters).  It's hard to know what you really want here (why not tell us?) but I'm pretty sure that LIKE clause won't do what you think. But as for your stated question: please indicate what database this is (ORACLE? MSSQL?  Something else?) and distinct values from c.vcCompanyNo if possible.  Likely (especially since LIKE is broken) you have nonnumerics there.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use `regexp` instead of `like`.  For all digits:

```
(CASE WHEN c.vcCompanyNo REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' 
      THEN CAST(c.vcCompanyNo AS UNSIGNED)
      ELSE 0
 END)
```

Note that MySQL does not support `BIGINT` in `CAST` (why?  I have no idea).

MySQL also supports implicit conversion with no errors.  So this might more simply do what you want:

```
(c.vcCompanyNo + 0)
```

This converts the leading digits to a number value.  If the first character is not a digit, then it returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The [like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator does not support regular expressions, only `_` and `%` operators.

You need the [rlike](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator instead. You also seem to be doing a double negation (`not like` and `[^...]`). `rlike '[0-9]'` should do the trick.